How to get 'classic' ftp (not sftp) running under bookworm?
I have several Raspi's running under bookworm. On one of them (Raspi Zero) I succeeded to get ftp working (I mean the 'classic' one, not sftp). I wanted to get ftp also running on another Raspi (Raspi 5) and as 'classic' ftp is not standard available in bookworm, I started with installing ftp (as client): sudo apt install ftp. The installation succeeded, but I could not connect to our site where our website is hosted.
I vaguely remember doing some additional things to get ftp working on the Raspi Zero, but I can't remember what and I can't find it on the internet anymore either.
Does anyone know how to get ftp working under bookworm?

The installation succeeded, but could not connect. perhaps what you try to connect to is the issue?

When I ftp to the server of our website on the Raspi 5, I get no response.
When I ftp to the server of our website on the Zero, I get the username and password prompts and the connection is ready to send files.

oh, is the raspi 5 supposed to be the ftp server? I believe the ftp pacakge is a client

To send files to another computer (in this case the host of our website), the Raspi does not need to be a server. It only needs to act as a client.

your keep contradicting yourself then

Stop commenting on your post. Edit your question with any details.

Please edit your question and make more clear which involved Raspi is the server and which is supposed to be the client. Which FTP server are you running? Did you try another FTP client just to ensure that the  ftp  client is not a problem? Did you check the security settings on the server side? Maybe it blocks requests from certain computers because of the setup?

get classic ftp running ... ftp what?  client or server?

Welcome -- but you have only outlined what you did in an abstract way.  It is then impossible for anyone to say what you might have done wrong.  You need to explain in detail how you installed ftp, how you start the server, and what its logs have to say.

For a start apt-get has been obsolete for years.
There is no need to install anything; ftp works out of the box and you are perfectly capable of disabling security if you so choose and the server allows insecure access.
Certainly to use as an ftp client you don't need to do anything.

ftp is not standard available in bookworm.
